# How can I read json content inside a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

So when I want to put a Google +1 button on webpages, I would do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {lang: 'zh-TW'}
</script>
```

But I am wondering, there is an object in the script tag, but it is also loading `plusone.js`! At the end the script can also get the object inside the tag. How does Google do that? Unlike normally I would not put anything inside.  Normally I would do

```
<script type"text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: they parse the string contents of the last inserted script tag as json.

Comment: Closed as too localized? Why?

Comment: @Derek: I believe it was the tone of your post. You should rewrite it to show specifically what you want to do and what you've tried, and not ask how "Google" does it but how *you* can do it. "How does Google do this?" is a horrible question title.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I think it is the reason. Not good in writing questions...

Comment: Perhaps plusone.js ends with an open variable assignation, such as "var lang ="?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the URL is known, it's simple enough:

```
JSON.parse(
    document.querySelector("script[src='https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js']")
        .innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')
);
```

---

That said, as Alohci pointed out in the comments, the last script on the page will be the last one loaded when the script runs, because (unless specified otherwise) scripts are blocking. Therefore, this would work:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var data = JSON.parse(scripts[scripts.length-1].innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''));
```

Comment: I think this works too: `src="//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"`

Comment: Since the script runs as soon as it is parsed, I believe a common practice is just to get the last script element in the DOM, rather than rely on matching the src attribute.