# How to embed a google chart in javascript instead of HTML?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'd like to embed a ready made google chart, but without using the `<script>` tag.

When I go to Google Charts and press "Publish Chart", a window pops up saying that I should put this code anywhere in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js">
{"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=....","options":{"titleTextStyle":{"bold":true,"color":"#000","fontSize":16},"legendTextStyle":{"bold":true,"color":"#000000","fontSize":12},"animation":{"duration":0},"width":600,"hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"viewWindowMode":null,"viewWindow":null,"maxValue":null},"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"title":null,"minValue":null,"viewWindow":{"max":null,"min":null},"maxValue":null},{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"viewWindow":{"max":null,"min":null},"maxValue":null}],"booleanRole":"certainty","title":"A title","height":371,"legend":"right","focusTarget":"series","tooltip":{"trigger":"none"},"isStacked":false},"state":{},"view":{},"isDefaultVisualization":false,"chartType":"ColumnChart","chartName":"Chart 1"}
</script>
```

It would be very easy, just copy and paste... The problem is that I can't put a `<script>` tag anywhere in the HTML, because the editor rejects it. I can only make a `<div id="mychart"></div>` in the HTML and add something to a javascript file which will be loaded at the end of `<head>`.

So, my javascript code would do something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#mychart").text("google chart here...");
});
```

But I can't figure out how to embed the chart mentioned above into this code (it's just a script tag with json chart definition).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: So I can load a remote script with getScript. But what to do with the json object, which is below the script tag?

Comment: Stick whatever script you need into external `JS` files and load them in sequence using one of the methods above. It doesn't need to be remote. It can be part of your own website.

Comment: Simply appending a json object after a getScript function looks strange and results in "Invalid token" js error. I think what the original code is doing may be something described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494659/how-can-i-read-json-content-inside-a-script-tag . Anyway, I realized that for new sheets the embed code is an iframe (which I have no problem inserting into HTML). The sheet that I tried to publish was from 2012. I transfered the sheet to new and the problem is gone.